# Android - Remove padding from button

Tags: android

How can I remove the padding from a `Button` view?
At least I need to have equal padding on all sides no matter what.

I have this

```
<Button
   style="@style/btnStart"
   android:text="@string/start" />
```

And this style

```
<style name="btnStart" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_start_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/selector_start_button_text</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>                       
</style>
```

And this drawable `selector_start_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/start_button" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/start_button" android:width="1dp" />
        <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />            
    </shape>            
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/start_button" android:width="1dp" />            
            <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But I still get this

[image: button with unwanted padding]

Comment: android:padding="0px"

Comment: <Button
   style="@style/btnStart"
   android:text="@string/start" 
android:padding="0px"/>

Comment: also no effect, that is the first thing I tried

Comment: That black color is Button's background or activity's background?

Comment: checkout source code for "@android:style/Widget.Button" might solve your problem! maybe that has a custom padding defined

Answer (score 8):

Maybe your button is inheriting a minHeight. Try overriding it:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    .../>
```

Comment: I was creating a custom Style for a button. Since it inherits from android:Widget.Button it has a defined minHeight. This saved my night!